# Passing date parameter to jdbc query in Mule

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, mule

I have a flow in Mule where I want to use a date parameter i get from one query as an input for another query.

```
<jdbc:connector name="myConnector" transactionPerMessage="false" dataSource-ref="myDataSource">
    <jdbc:query key="getPollTimes" value="SELECT to_char(last_poll_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as last_poll_start, to_char(last_poll_end, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as last_poll_end FROM db_sources WHERE source_system = 'mySystem'" />
    <jdbc:query key="getCustomerIds" value="SELECT id FROM customers WHERE updated &lt; TO_DATE(#[variable:last_poll_end],'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')" />
</jdbc:connector>

<flow name="myFlow">
    <enricher>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="getPollTimes" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <enrich target="#[variable:last_poll_end]" source="#[groovy:payload.last_poll_end]"/>
    </enricher>
    <logger level="INFO" message="last_poll_end = #[variable:last_poll_end]" />
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="getCustomerIds" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
</flow>
```

When running this I cannot get this to work (note that I am using an Oracle DB). I have included the exception below. Have anyone encountered this?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Invalid column type(SQL Code: 17004, SQL State: + null) (java.sql.SQLException)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError:113 (null)
2. Invalid column type Query: SELECT ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE UPDATED < TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') Parameters: [[2000-01-01]](SQL Code: 17004, SQL State: + null) (java.sql.SQLException)
  org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner:540 (null)
3. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=jdbc://getCustomerIds, connector=JdbcConnector
{
  name=myConnector
  lifecycle=start
  this=668e94
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=false
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[jdbc]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.jdbc.getCustomerIds', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={queryTimeout=-1}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: ArrayList (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:106 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `INFO  2012-01-03 08:27:00,030 [scheduler-TalentumESB_Worker-12] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: last_poll_end = [2000-01-01]`

This is followed by the exception in my original post.

Comment: The logger clearly shows the issue is in the selection part, not the insertion.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. The issue was partly that the date variable I got back from the first query was stored as an array. To resolve this i pick out the first element. Besides that I removed the to_date() in the second sql query.

This gets the first element in the array:

```
<enrich target="#[variable:last_poll_end]" source="#[groovy:payload.last_poll_end[0]]"/>
```

The updated sql:

```
<jdbc:query key="getCustomerIds" value="SELECT id FROM customers WHERE updated &lt; #[variable:last_poll_end]" />
```